# Retrieve value of embedded array in json

Tags: go

Given the following code (snippets)
I struggle to get the value of "dns_addresses" out.

I assume it is an embedded array, but what ever I have tried, nothing.
Any tips?

Regards, Darrell.

Json Input.

```
{
   "dns_addresses":[
      "192.168.178.2"
   ],
   "dns_port":53,
   "http_port":80,
   "protection_enabled":true,
   "dhcp_available":true,
   "running":true,
   "version":"v0.105.2",
   "language":""
}
```

Code snippet.

```
type Status struct {
    version            string
    protection_enabled bool
    dhcp_available     bool
    running            bool
    ip                 []string
}

func main() {
    ...
    ...
    var input map[string]interface{}
    response := httpRequest("status")

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(response), &input)
    fmt.Printf("body: %s\n", response)
    ...
    ...
    data.running = input["running"].(bool)
    data.version = input["version"].(string)
    data.ip = input["dns_addresses"].([]string)
    ...
    ...
    fmt.Printf("data stored: %+v\n", data)
}
```

Output:

```
Starting the application...
body: {"dns_addresses":["192.168.178.2"],"dns_port":53,"http_port":80,"protection_enabled":true,"dhcp_available":true,"running":true,"version":"v0.105.2","language":""}

input data: map[dhcp_available:%!s(bool=true) dns_addresses:[192.168.178.2] dns_port:%!s(float64=53) http_port:%!s(float64=80) language: protection_enabled:%!s(bool=true) running:%!s(bool=true) version:v0.105.2]
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []string
```

Output is if "data.ip = input["dns_addresses"].([]string)" commented out.

```
data stored: &{version:v0.105.2 protection_enabled:true dhcp_available:true running:true ip:[]}
Terminating the application...
```

Comment: Why not unmarshal the json directly into the struct? You'd have to export the fields to make that work, but that's a fair price to pay for not having to deal with the `interface{}` type.

Comment: Using a struct: https://play.golang.org/p/_FS5SebjKda Using a map: https://play.golang.org/p/6hJ4ot0URg4 (note that "dns_addresses" is not `[]string` but `[]interface{}` so you need to manually convert that to `[]string` with a [loop](https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface))

Comment: Thank you, It looks cleaner doing it like https://play.golang.org/p/_FS5SebjKda

Answer (score 0):

1-) always do error handling

2-) are you sure that `response` has correct value

3-) are you sure that input has correct value

I don't see another problem. maybe try using [a tool like that](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) to be more sure about your structure.

Comment: Thank you for the response: The response is valid.